# Linker cannot find standard c library

Tags: gcc, shared-libraries, centos7

I have some problem with libraries on CentOS. I am not sure what's wrong. When I try to make a project, I get this error:

```
gcc -Wall -Winline -O2 -fPIC -g -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -o bzip2 bzip2.o -L. -lbz2
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lc
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I can - and did - make a symlink that links `/usr/lib64/libc.so` to `/usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so` which exists, but that just creates another error:

```
gcc -Wall -Winline -O2 -fPIC -g -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -o bzip2 bzip2.o -L. -lbz2
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x12): undefined reference to `__libc_csu_fini'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x19): undefined reference to `__libc_csu_init'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Obviously the toolchain is broken. How can I fix it correctly? Making symlinks obviously isn't fixing anything...

I also tried to reinstall whole development toolchain using `yum group remove  "Development Tools"` then `yum group install "Development Tools"`

Comment: Shouldn't you be compiling with `g++`?

Comment: @Rakete1111 No, it's a C library. The makefile isn't mine. The problem is that whole gcc toolchain seems to be broken. I reinstalled it with no success.

Comment: @TomášZato Remember that order matters when specifying the libraries.

Comment: The command lines do not look right: `-Wall -Winline -O2 -fPIC -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64` are compiler flags, but it is a linker invocation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/usr/lib64/libc.so` is not a symbolic link, it is a linker script.

On Fedora it contains:

```
/* GNU ld script
   Use the shared library, but some functions are only in
   the static library, so try that secondarily.  */
OUTPUT_FORMAT(elf64-x86-64)
GROUP ( /lib64/libc.so.6 /usr/lib64/libc_nonshared.a  AS_NEEDED ( /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 ) )
```

And, sure enough:

```
$ nm -C --defined-only /usr/lib64/libc_nonshared.a

elf-init.oS:
0000000000000070 T __libc_csu_fini
0000000000000000 T __libc_csu_init
...
```

`/usr/lib64/libc.so` belongs to `glibc` rpm. I suggest reinstalling it.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to reinstall `glibc`.